# Azure AD OAuth2: Check if user consent is disabled?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory

When sending users to authenticate with Azure AD OAuth2 we often encounter organizations that have disabled that users can consent to sharing their data (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-consent-requests#disable-all-future-user-consent-operations-to-any-application).

We are wondering if there is a way to query this before we send users to the login with Microsoft and show them the information that they need to get their administrator to perform tenant-wide consent before they can login?

Essentially can we figure out if the following is configured to allow user consent or not:

[image]

Bonus: How to check if the permissions we are requesting are among the "selected permissions" classified as "low impact"?

Some related questions:

- [Question how to directly to go to Admin consent page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36725922/278842)
- [Answer pointing out that users can't consent if the publisher isn't verified (we are verified)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65246837/278842)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to check whether ‘User’s consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf setting’ is set to ‘Yes’ or not. Also, and when this setting is set to yes, the ‘Allow user consent for apps (All users can consent for any app to access the organization data)’ setting in ‘Consent and Permissions’ section is also set. Thus, you can use the below powershell script to check whether the above said setting is set or not: -

Note: - You will need administrator permissions and privileges on the Azure AD for which you need to check the above consent and permissions for.

```
  ‘ Install-Module AzureAD
    $cred=Get-Credential
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred
    Get-AzureADTenantDetail | fl UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled ’

    Output: - UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled : True
```

Also, if you need to request the above for a particular app hosted in Azure AD, you can do so through Microsoft Graph API query but the user id used while authenticating to Graph API should have read permissions (User.Read.All) on the Azure AD for which you need to request the consent permissions for as Microsoft Graph will be the resource identifier here.

Below is an example of the Graph API query for your reference: -

```
 ‘ GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &response_mode=query
   &scope=
   https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.read%20
   https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.send
   &state=12345 ’
```

Once you run the above query likewise for your requested app in Azure AD and if the user has consented to the said permissions for the app, it will go ahead and access the app by giving the required permissions like offline_access and if not, it will give out an error message.

Comment: Dear Kartik! I appreciate your answer, but it misses the point that I am the author of the app in this case and not the administrator of the user's AD. So I do not have the permissions for these calls. It makes sense that what I want is likely not possible.

Comment: Yes sure, what you want to achieve needs read permission from the client's side AD to query and get information about the user's consent. Thank you